# Unable to populate my RecyclerView with the conversation from the user and DialogFlow(api.ai)

Tags: java, android, firebase, dialogflow-es

I am trying to build an android chat bot application using FirebaseDatabase and DialogFlow(api.ai) and I am using RecyclerView to Load the messages into the app. But I am unable to load messages into the app, every time it shows blank screen when I run the app.

I have tried all the suggested answers on StackOverflow but still I am unable to load messages into the app.

**MainActivity**

```
import ai.api.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.AIListener;
import ai.api.AIServiceException;
import ai.api.android.AIDataService;
import ai.api.android.AIService;
import ai.api.model.AIError;
import ai.api.model.AIRequest;
import ai.api.model.AIResponse;
import ai.api.model.Result;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.firebase.ui.database.SnapshotParser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editText;
    RelativeLayout addBtn;
    DatabaseReference ref;


    private AIService aiService;
    private Context context;


   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, chat_rec>adapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.TEXT);
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final ai.api.android.AIConfiguration configuration = new ai.api.android.AIConfiguration("8c9665a53fba45d9a3015e0ba7330417", AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,

                ai.api.android.AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

        aiService = AIService.getService(this, configuration);
        aiService.setListener(this);

        final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();
        final AIDataService aiDataService = new AIDataService(context, configuration);



        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);




        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.keepSynced(true);

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);





                String message = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!message.equals("")) {

                    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").push();

                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, "user");
                    ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);
                    ChatMessage model1 = new ChatMessage();
                        model1.setMessageUser(chatMessage.toString());
                    new AsyncTask<AIRequest, Void, AIResponse>() {


                        @Override
                        protected AIResponse doInBackground(AIRequest... aiRequests) {

                            final AIRequest request = aiRequests[0];
                            try {
                                final AIResponse response = aiDataService.request(aiRequest);
                            } catch (AIServiceException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(AIResponse response) {
                            if (response != null) {
                                Result result = response.getResult();
                                String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                                ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(reply, "bot");
                                ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }.execute(aiRequest);

                } else {
                    aiService.startListening();
                }
                editText.setText("");

            }
        });

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });




        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage>options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(ref, ChatMessage.class)
                .build();



        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, chat_rec>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final chat_rec holder, int i, @NonNull final ChatMessage model) {
                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("chat").getValue()).equals( model.getMessageUser())) {
                                holder.rightText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                                holder.rightText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                            }
                            else {
                                holder.leftText.setText(model.getMessageText());

                                holder.leftText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }






                });



            }


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public chat_rec onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.messagelist, parent, false);
                return new chat_rec(view);
            }

        };



        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);

                int msgCount = adapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (msgCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);

                }



            }

        });




        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(AIResponse result) {
        Result result1 = result.getResult();
        String message = result1.getResolvedQuery();
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, "user");
        ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);

        String reply = result1.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
        ChatMessage chatMessage1 = new ChatMessage(reply,"bot");
        ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(AIError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningCanceled() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningFinished() {

    }


}
```

*Can somebody please let me know what changes I should make, so that I can make this thing work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to this problem. Instead of populating the RecyclerView. One can create two different xml layouts - Bot Layout and User Layout.

**Bot message layout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/botMsgLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bot_bg_bubble"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/adamina"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="1sp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Hello There!"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**User message layout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userMsgLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/user_bg_bubble"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Hello!"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, in MainActivity inflate the above layouts using a switch case according to the required needs.

Comment: Great that you came back and solve the issue! You can mark it as an accepted answer then to close the questions.